# Ionic framework : ion-item with three columns and three rows

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Is possible create an ion-item with inside three columns and three rows ?? 
I tried this  but it doesn't work for me:

```
<ion-item class="no-padding item-text-wrap">
      <ion-item-content> column 1 </ion-item-content>
      <ion-item-content> column 2 </ion-item-content>
      <ion-item-content> column 2 </ion-item-content>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Does this help? http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid

Comment: I going to try it but i think that it's not enough, because I need to use into a ng-repeat, do you say that I have to put the grid tag into the ion-item??